# Why does media wiki install stop?

Tags: apache-httpd, php, wiki

I am building a new MediaWiki installation on a CentOS 6.4 system.

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   May 13 2013 22:11:16

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

MediaWiki 1.21.1
```

`mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.69, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

I can reach the index.php page and get this message

```
MediaWiki 1.21.1

LocalSettings.php not found.

Please set up the wiki first.
```

When I click on the `Please set up the wiki first.` hyperlink,

This is the URL, which is correct.

`http://appcentral:8587/mw-config/index.php`

The page stays blank, and nothing happens. What should I check to see what is going wrong. This is a fresh, clean installation. There is no existing MySQL DB already setup for the wiki.

Here is the error in error.log under /var/log/httpd.

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/arlington_it/includes/cache/LocalisationCache.php on line 546, referer: http://localhost:8587/index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First order of business, find out what logs files are currently being written to:

```
sudo ls -ltrh /var/log/httpd
```

The files at the bottom of the list are the most recently modified.

The error messages generated by PHP are probably going to `php_errors.log` or `error_log` or `ssl_error_log`

Try running a `tail -f` on these files while reproducing your error, they may reveal useful information. For example:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I needed to install php-xml and restart httpd. The answer was found [here](http://vanillaforums.org/discussion/22002/fatal-error-class-domdocument-not-found-in-var-www-html-community-answers).